# Invalid Argument on basic API call using UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm new to Google Apps Scripts and I've been trying to make a simple Get call to a URL.  I make this call from my browser: https://accounting.sageone.co.za/api/1.1.1/Supplier/Get?apikey={4CFEEFE1-CE04-425F-82C3-DCB179C817D5}&companyid=164740 and get the respons I'm looking for. I now try to make the call from Google Apps Scripts using the following code:

```
function myFunction() {
var url = 'https://accounting.sageone.co.za/api/1.1.1/Supplier/Get?apikey={4CFEEFE1-CE04-425F-82C3-DCB179C817D5}&companyid=164740
var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
Logger.log(response);
}'
```

I get a respons stating '
Message details
Invalid argument: https://accounting.sageone.co.za/api/1.1.1/Supplier/Get?apikey={4CFEEFE1-CE04-425F-82C3-DCB179C817D5}&companyid=164740 (line 4, file "Code")'

I've tried a whole bunch of permutations with no luck...

Answer (score 5):

When using UrlFetchApp, you need to enter your URL parameters as part of a request parameters rather than in the URL itself. For a `GET` request these go directy as part of the parameters, for a `POST` request the parameters would be part of a payload object. [Reference Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl-params)

Here is a modified function:

```
function myFunction() {
  var url = 'https://accounting.sageone.co.za/api/1.1.1/Supplier/Get'  
  var params = {
    "method": 'GET',
    "apikey": "{4CFEEFE1-CE04-425F-82C3-DCB179C817D5}",
    "companyid": "164740"
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params);
  Logger.log(response)
}
```

Note: This corrects your method, however, the server still requires further authentication. If you run into issues with that, ask another questions specific to that issue as well.